# Ancient non CLI ember project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, deprecated

I have a very outdated ember project and I have updated my codebase to use the latest version of `jQuery 3.4.0`. The problem is, there is `deprecated` jQuery code in the ember app and it's causing errors. The one error I am seeing is `fixHooks`. This has long been deprecated in jQuery. However, the ember app is pulling in

`cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.7.0/ember.min.js` (Yeah, ancient)

which uses `fixHooks`.

Do you know of a way or workaround I could do to get this to play nice with the `newest version of jQuery`?

Comment: which version of ember are you using? How do you load jQuery in your app?

Comment: I am using ember 1.7.0 and jquery is simply included in the head of my website.

Comment: honestly you probably should rewrite on ember 3. While you probably can reuse some code, you have to check every line because you're literally before the upgrade path that effectivly started with `ember-cli`.